# Проверка формы ФИО в С++ cli

Tags: регулярные-выражения, winforms, c++-cli

Пытаюсь написать регулярные выражения для проверки формы с ФИО, нужно чтобы не допускались другие символы кроме кириллицы. В чем ошибка?

```
String^ name_test = "";
name_test = dNameTD->Text;
Regex^ r = gcnew Regex("([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[\-\s]?){3,}");
Match^ name_ex = r->Match(name_test);

if (name_test != "") {
    if (name_ex->Success) {
        label1->Text = "Oк";
    }
    else {
        label1->Text = "Не ок";
    }
}
```

Comment: Как обычно - `\s` -> `\\s`. У вас получается шаблон в виде `([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[-s]?){3,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `\s` на `\\s`, иначе у вас получается шаблон в виде `([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[-s]?){3,}`.

```
Regex^ r1 = gcnew Regex("([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[-\\s]?){3,}");
```

Экранировать `-` в начале символьного класса не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй этот вариант:
`"/[^,\p{Cyrillic}]/ui"`